# Что такое авраамиться?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

В словаре Даля не очень понятно написано. Также интересует этимология

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос цитату из словаря Даля.

Comment: Авраамиться, ханжить благочестием. Не Авраамься, не Исаакся, не Иаковься, не ханжи.